# Using javascript to reveal a hidden div slowly and in "dropdown" style

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a small block that contains something like this: `Login | Register`

When the user clicks `Login`, the block extends below and reveals a form for the user to login. Clicking `Login` again hides the form again.

The same goes for when a user clicks on `Register` (but with a different form). If `Login or Register` is clicked when the other form is visible, the newly selected form should be made visible and the other should disappear.

I would like to do more than just make the forms appear out of thin air. I'm trying to get it to "dropdown" with a very small amount of lag. Similarly, it should "rollup" when the form is re-toggled.

If this is simple to do, could someone provide some code? If it is a little more involved maybe an explanation or a link that would help me figure it out myself would be very helpful.

Comment: I know you make a request for some code, but you should take a crack at it first and then post what you have in this question to help users give you a good answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a framework such as [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) to simplify this for you. It simplifies and normalizes all the bad parts of JavaScript so coding JS can become fun again. Unless you are a guru and understand all the design flaws and inconsistencies between "JavaScript" and "JScript", a framework is the way to go. JQuery is only one of a handful. If you don't prefer the syntax of JQuery, you can research [Mootools](http://mootools.net/), [Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/), or [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/):

```
$('#login').click(function(){
    $('#loginForm').slideToggle('fast');
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vNeXq/

Comment: If he is new to javascript, chances are he's not heard of JQuery yet. This is a good place to start: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials

Comment: @ivarni is right, I'm not sure what JQuery is. But the `slideToggle` looks like it's what I need. Time to learn :) Thanks to both.